# ASP.Net Providers for MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, open-source, provider

Are there ASP.NET 2.0 Providers available for MySQL? On Googling, I find discrete (and incomplete) pieces of code on codeplex and elsewhere.

Alternatively there is dotConnect from Devart, however, it is commercial. I am looking for something that is open source, free & production quality.

The one that I am looking for should cover at least following:
 - Membership
 - Role management
 - Profile
 - Session state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did more Googling and came across [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-asp-provider.html). It provides support for the ASP.NET 2.0 provider model.

MySQL Connector/NET supplies the following providers:

- Membership Provider
- Role Provider
- Profile Provider
- Session State Provider (MySQL Connector/NET 6.1 and later)

I'll try it out and share my feedback subsequently.

Comment: Hello. As I said I'll give feedback. I've tried out the membership & role providers and they seem to be working flawlessly and were easy to configure. Just one point to note: There is no separate script to create database schema for providers. One needs to configure the provider in machine.config with the attribute autogenerateschema="true" which generates schema automatically at runtime. My objection is that if I plan to have membership & session state on separate databases, both databases will carry all providers' tables.